# AWS permissions to access Account and Billing info

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an IAM user with Administrator permissions.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

but when I try to access "/billing" page AWS says

```
You are not authorized to perform this operation.
You are currently signed in as an IAM user that does not have permissions to the requested page.
```

I also tried to generate a specific policies like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1438861751000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aws-portal:ViewBilling"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But it doesn't change anything. I still can't access the billing info.

When I go to policy simulation page it says that permission is allowed for the user.

I've seen the AWS guide and tried to follow it. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-permissions-ref.html

Is there something I'm missing? What could it be?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an account setting to enable IAM user access in addition to the permissions on individual accounts. On the [billing home page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/account), 
scroll down and look for **IAM User Access to Billing Information**.  It might look like this:

[image: Screenshot of IAM User Access to Billing (before)]

You need to edit and update this to allow IAM user access:

[image: Screenshot of IAM User Access to Billing (after)]

Comment: Thanks ! With really helps.